# Qt - C++ - Function of the child accessed through parent with connect

Tags: c++, qt, casting

Sorry if the title isn't really explicit. Here is the example, a `classA` has several child, `childA1`, `childA2` etc.. stored in a `list` of `classA` :

```
QList<ClassA> listA;
listA << childA1() << childA2();
```

The `childA1` has the function `start()` which doesn't exist in `classA`. So if I try :

```
listA[0].start();
```

The compiler says that `classA` has no member `start()`.
`start()` being a public slot, I've done :

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(signalStart()), listA[0], SLOT(start()));
```

And it's working. So my question is how can he know this function `start()` after being stored as `classA` in the list ? Is there a way to know the "original" type ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt signals/slots work using introspection (the ability to list methods and properties of any `QObject` at runtime).

Qt utilizes the [Meta-Object Compiler](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/moc.html) tool to have introspection capabilities in C++. You may want to have a look at [this blog post](https://woboq.com/blog/how-qt-signals-slots-work.html) for more information on the internals of Qt signals/slots.

You can use introspection without signals/slots. So, in your example, You don't need to define the signal `signalStart()` just to be able to invoke the `start()` method. Instead, You can do something like this:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(listA[0], "start");
```

This will look for the function named start in the specified `QObject` (regardless of the pointer type), and invoke it.

Here is a fully working example of using introspection:

```
#include <QtCore>

QTextStream& qOut(){static QTextStream out(stdout); return out;}

class MyObject : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyObject(QObject* parent= nullptr):QObject(parent){}
    ~MyObject(){}
    //Object has a slot named func
    Q_SLOT void func(){ qOut() << "Hello func!\n"; }
};

int main(int , char*[]){
    QObject* object = new MyObject();

    //print the object's class name (this is the real class name!)
    qOut() << object->metaObject()->className() << "\n";

    //look for a function named func in the object, and invoke it
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(object, "func");

    return 0;
}

//run MOC on this CPP file
#include "main.moc"
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should store pointers of your objects in `QList`.

Then you could use `dynamic_cast` to determine which child type your object is:

```
A *obj = listA[0];

if (A1 *a1 = dynamic_cast<A1 *>(obj)) {
    // This is an A1 object, you can call start()
    a1->start();
} else if (A2 *a2 = dynamic_cast<A2 *>(obj)) {
    // This is an A2 object
}
```